# Eureka Client running with name "UNKNOWN" in eureka server UI

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I created a Eureka server spring boot application. It is properly loaded. After that I am trying to create a Eureka client.But it is not getting listed in eureka server UI. I am adding my client application details.

My main controller class file is as below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZEurekaClientServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZEurekaClientServiceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

And my pom.xml contains the ,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And my application.properties file containing,

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8071/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
```

When It client is running , the eureka server UI not showing it's name. ONly showing UNKNOWN as application. I am adding its screenshot below.[image]

What I need to display the application name instead of "UNKNOWN" in the eureka server UI? Is there is any additional settings to add application name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify the application name by setting it either in your `application.yml` or in your `application.properties`.

For application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: {YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME}
```

For application.properties:

```
spring.application.name={YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME}
```

Comment: Yes. I got it.its working. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
spring.application.name=(Your Name)
```

In application.properties file

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the **property (yml) file could not be copied to the target folder** due to a build problem.

If this happens, none of the yml properties will load and the **spring boot program will run with the default configuration**.

For example, **Tomcat started with 8080**, **not** any port you specified in the yml file

[image]